# WPF ListView not updating

Tags: c#, wpf

I have got a list view and bind ItemSource to public ObservableCollection StockList { get; set; }. I initiated the StoclList in the Constructor method. I am getting filtered stock list from a ViewModel and adding these items to this StcokList but somehow ListView doesn't show the list items.

But if i set ItemsSource="{Binding ListFromViewModel}" It works..

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window     {   

    public MainWindowViewModel viewModel;
    public ObservableCollection<StockModel> StockList { get; set; }

    //Constructor
    public MainWindow()
    {
        StockList = new ObservableCollection<StockModel>();
        InitializeComponent();
        viewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();
        this.DataContext = viewModel;           
    }

    private async void BtnSelectFile_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        GetData();
        viewModel.StartProcessing(progress);
        StockList.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < viewModel.ListOfStocks.Count; i++)
        {
            StockList.Add(viewModel.ListOfStocks[i]);
        }
    }
```

And my XAML file is like this

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="LvErrorList" ItemsSource="{Binding StockList}">
```

UPDATE: If i use this code, it start working. But I am not sure why!!!

```
LvErrorList.ItemsSource = StockList;
```

Comment: StockList is a property of the MainWindow class, while you set the DataContext to a MainWindowViewModel instance. How is that supposed to work? Did you intend to have the StockList property in MainWindowViewModel? What is the purpose of the view model otherwise?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Clemens. So because I set this.DataContext = viewModel; My MainWindow.xaml will ignore all my MainWindow bindings? Bindings only work if i declare it inside the ViewModeClass?

Comment: Unless you explicitly set the source object of a Binding, it uses the current DataContext. Not sure if it makes sense, but you could write `ItemsSource="{Binding StockList, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"`. But the property should of course be in a view model class, when you already have one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you type `{Binding StockList}` in your XAML markup, WPF will try to bind to the `StockList` property of the current `DataContext` of the `ListView`.

Since the ListView inherits its `DataContext` from the parent element all the way up to the parent window, it will look for the property in the `MainWindowViewModel` object which you have set as the `DataContext` in the constructor of the window.

If you set the `DataContext` the the instance of a class where the `StockList` property is defined, i.e. the window itself in this case, your binding will work:

```
this.DataContext = this;
```

Alternatively, you could move the `StockList` property to the view model or opt out of the `DataContext` by specifying an explicit source for the binding. This will bind to the `StockList` property of the window itself regardless of the `DataContext`:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="LvErrorList"
    ItemsSource="{Binding StockList, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}">
```

Please refer to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-binding-overview?view=netdesktop-5.0?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001077) for more information about data binding in WPF and how it works.